# Save AJAX responses in Arrays

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm having X and Y coordinates in my MySQL table. I have them in my php file putting them in an associative array

```
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['x'];
    echo $row['y'];
}
```

I want to save them in my html file ( with javascript) in 2 Arrays.
How is this possible? Can I use for example a javascript loop which switches from saving the output (the x and y coordinates) in different arrays?

Thanks for every response!

Comment: You want those PHP values in JS??

Comment: Come on, another Ajax JSON question? Please use google before asking...

Comment: Your question is very confusing. The title says you want to use AJAX, but the question says that you want to put them into the HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them into a PHP array, then convert that to Javascript using `json_encode`.

```
$array = array();
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $array[] = array('x' => $row['x'], 'y' => $row['y']);
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

In the Javascript, the AJAX callback function can use `JSON.parse()` to convert this to an array of objects.

If you want two arrays, push the `x` and `y` values onto different arrays, then combine them in the JSON response.

```
$xarray = array();
$yarray = array();
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $xarray[] = $row['x'];
    $yarray[] = $row['y'];
}
echo json_encode(array('x' => $xarray, 'y' => $yarray));
```

Then in the Javascript you do:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
var xarray = obj.x;
var yarray = obj.y;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But when I try to use  JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText) it says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0".

Comment: That means your AJAX script is outputting HTML before the JSON. It shouldn't produce any output except the `echo json_encode($array);`. line.

Comment: Sorry that I'm new to this! But now how can I have 2 arrays with the x and y coordinates in javascript when I have done    echo  json_encode($array);

Comment: You can only return one object or array with JSON, so you have to combine them. I've shown how to do that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `json_encode`?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

This will let you print the arrays directly into JavaScript. For instance:

```
<?php
    $coord = array(
        'x' => 52,
        'y' => 17,
    );
?>

<script>
var coords = <?php echo json_encode($coord); ?>;
</script>
```

will print

```
<script>
var coords = {"x":52,"y":17};
</script>
```